# after \paragraph{} return to main text

Tags: sectioning, formatting, line-breaking, paragraphs, sections-paragraphs

I was wondering whether after a \paragraph{*paragraph_title*} environment I might return to the main text. If so, how can I properly do it in latex?

Example:

```
\section{Why does the Sun shine?}
main text

\paragraph{Nuclear reactions}
paragraph text

main text pt. 2
```

With this code, the *main text pt. 2* figures as a second paragraph of the \paragraph{} on nuclear reactions. Not as a paragraph of the main section.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: latex has no way of marking the end of a section it just marks section headings.  Note `\paragraph` is a 4th level heading so should just follow `\subsubsection` not `\section`.  How would you want to indicate to a reader that a subsection has ended?

Comment: To phrase that another way, if you have another paragraph after "main text" but before your `\paragraph`, it will look exactly the same as "main text pt. 2".  So it's not clear how you want to show that your paragraph is a part of the main section.

Comment: All section levels are "main" text (i.e, a text that take the fulll text width) so that level only end when another section level start. If you want a "subtext" with title, within  main text parasgraph,  a  `description` list is an easy and ready solution as this introduce a distinctive indentation, but alternatively could work also another ways to indent the text (quoting, for instance), or boxing it  (tcolorbox, for instance) or just change the font type. Hard to guess without know what is your preconceived idea of  the right highlight of a "subtext".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the paragraph environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{Why does the Sun shine?}
main text
\begin{paragraph}{Nuclear reactions}
Paragraph text
\end{paragraph}
main text pt. 2

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  I'm not sure this will work.  Without a blank line after the `end`, the next line is still part of the previous paragraph.  And with a blank line, I think that this is actually equivalent to OP's snippet, but with a `group` around the environment body.

Comment: putting a group around a section heading can have unexpected results, I would not recommend this.

Comment: I added the output from your suggested code. I'm not sure if that is the output the original poster wanted.